# Edit Contents for A Website

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-web-developer

I am not a front end programmer. My boss asked me to edit content of our company website. I have javascript, css, and html file.

How should I address content of our company website such as mail address?

Thank you!

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking and possibly too broad to be answered sufficiently here. Could you elaborate on anything in particular you're having trouble with?

Comment: Open the HTML file in a text editor, use Ctrl+F or some equivalent to find the  current mail address and change it to the new mail address. If you can't find it in the HTML file, try the JavaScript file.

Comment: You gotta really traverse the codebase to find out where the mail address is and change it  accordingly

Comment: I think most content should be in HTMI file. But mail address should be at page under "About us". However,  I cannot access other pages except main page by opening HTML file by Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little difficult to decipher what you're looking to accomplish. So I'll just go over a couple basics :)

**HTML files** act as the core structure of many sites. HTML files section off your site into blocks (Note the  tags in your HTML file), and can be used to insert text onto the page. HTML files frequently reference **CSS Files**. CSS Files are used to format the regions and materials created in the HTML file (Like Colors, Margins, Padding, etc). If you're not looking to change the appearance of your site, then modifying the CSS file is not likely what you're looking to do. **Javascript** has a wide variety of uses. Usually, a developer would use Javascript to incorporate some arbitrary "Event" or "Action" (Like Dynamically changing content)

From your question, it sounds as though your boss is not asking you to change the functionality of your site, rather just the content. In that case, my first recommendation would be to direct you to the HTML File. HTML files are not encoded, so you can open them in a text editor. However, I would recommend you use an IDE (Integrated Development Environment). Download Brackets IDE to modify your HTML file with convenience. It was developed by Adobe Systems and works great. http://brackets.io/

If you are looking to simply change a mailing address, then find the mailing address in your HTML file, and replace it with your new address. If your HTML file is very large, then you can search the entire file using a hotkey (Ctrl + F).

If you would like to understand the HTML language better, I would recommend W3 Schools https://www.w3schools.com/html/ . This tutorial will help you understand what you're looking at in the HTML (Just in case your file requires some additional editing)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

One, you could open the file online in cPanel or open it using ftp editor like atom.

Or two, to create a button and input to change it:

```
var input = document.getElementById(‘inputnamehere’).value;
document.getElementById(‘spanidorh1-6id’).innerHTML=input;
```